# Python Continuous Integration: Ignoring certain unit tests

Tags: python, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I'm working on a Python project that uses Travis CI. There is a class within the project that handles interaction with an external, non-Python application. Access to this application requires an account with a certain organization, and thus I don't believe it is possible for Travis to download and install it. That aside, I still want to have unit tests for this class. Is there a way to indicate to Travis that a given subset of the unit tests in the package should be ignored?

Comment: A unit test should always mock all of its dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than skip the tests, you should mock the calls to the external api so that you can unit test your code without the other app being present.  For more info see https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html.